# Tango Unity Object Recognition

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm actually making a tango application using unity, but i have an hard time with this technology, especially with how to use the cloud point.

I want to be able to compare an object in the room with a library of model when i press it on the screen. For this i want to use the cloud point system. And i think that the best way to do this is to recognise the floor under the object that interest me and get all the point above it.

My problem is here, i don't know how ask unity to get that point cloud, and compare it with the model in my library.How do i know in the TangoPointCloudData which point get which index? Is it possible to get a floor if there is an object on it?

I know it's a lot of question, and it's not the more precise thing i could give you, but i hope you will find a way to answer me.
Thanks.